# getting error while feeding inferences of one model to the generator of another model in keras

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer, pre-trained-model

I have designed an autoencoder and trained it. Now, I want to extract features from the encoder and feed them to the generator of another model.

This is the autoencoder I have implemented.

```
    x = Conv1D(64, 5, activation="relu", padding="same")(input) 
    #x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(2, padding="same")(x)
    x = Conv1D(32, 5, activation="relu", padding="same")(x) 
    #x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(2, padding="same")(x)
    x = Conv1D(16, 5, activation="relu", padding="same")(x) 
    x = MaxPooling1D(2, padding="same")(x)
    x = Conv1D(1, 5, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
    encoded = MaxPooling1D(2, padding="same")(x)


    x = Conv1D(1, 5, activation="relu", padding="same")(encoded) 
    #x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = UpSampling1D(2)(x) 
    x = Conv1D(16, 2, activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling1D(2)(x) 
    x = Conv1D(32, 2, activation='relu',padding='same')(x) 
    #x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = UpSampling1D(2, )(x) 
    x = Conv1D(64, 2, activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling1D(2, )(x) 
    decoded = Conv1D(1, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x) 

    autoencoder = Model(input, decoded)
```

This is where I am getting the outputs of the encoder part.

```
def extract_features_from_encoder(left,right):
   get_8th_layer_output = K.function([autoencoder.layers[0].input],

      [autoencoder.layers[8].output])

   left_encoded = get_8th_layer_output([left])[0]
   right_encoded = get_8th_layer_output([right])[0]
```

This is my generator:

```
def generator_encoded():
   left = ...
   right = ...

   left_encoded,right_encoded = 
   extract_features_from_encoder(left,right)

   yield ({'input_1': left_encoded, 'input_2': right_encoded}, 
   {'dense_1': y})
```

This is where I am calling the generator:

```
model.fit_generator(generator_encoded(),......)
```

This is my model.

```
input_l = Input(shape=(1000,1))
input_r = Input(shape=(1000,1))

shared_lstm = CuDNNLSTM(100)
encoded_l = shared_lstm(input_l)
encoded_r = shared_lstm(input_r)

L1_layer = Lambda(lambda tensors:K.abs(tensors[0] - tensors[1]))
L1_distance = L1_layer([encoded_l, encoded_r])

prediction = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(L1_distance)

model = Model(inputs=[input_l,input_r],outputs=prediction)
```

This is the error I am getting while running this model.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 
Tensor input_2:0, specified in either feed_devices or 
fetch_devices was not found in the Graph
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. Adding `with tf.Session:` before taking the inferences from the autoencoder made the issue disappear. The model needed to be told explicitly to use the default graph as there were multiple graphs instantiated.